# Integration by parts polynomial times logarithim

Tags: integration

$$\int \sqrt{x}\log_2(x) \, dx$$

Integral of Square root of x times log base 2 of x dx.

Comment: Since you know the method, what did you try before asking the question? Did you try to integrate the square, and then derive the log?

Comment: make log base 2 of x--> $ln(x)/(ln(2)$, $u = ln(x)$, $v' = \sqrt (x)$ so I get  $$2/3ln(x)x^1.5 - 2/3(\sqrt(x))/(ln(2))$$

Answer (score 1):

First lets change the base of the logarithm
$$\log_2(x)=\frac{\log_e(x)}{\log_e(2)}=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}$$ 
So your integral can be reformulated as 
$$\int\sqrt{x}\log_2(x)\,dx=\int\sqrt{x}\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}\,dx=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\int\sqrt{x}\ln(x)\,dx$$
Integrate by parts
$$\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\int\sqrt{x}\ln(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}[\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}\ln(x)-\frac{2}{3}\int x^{3/2}\cdot\frac{1}{x}\,dx]=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}[\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}\ln(x)-\frac{4}{9}x^{3/2}+c]$$

Comment: could I also get a hint for the integral of x(ln(x)) ? My idea was to set u as ln(x) and dv as x. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Ben:I think that is a good way to go because it is easier to integrate a function that is a power of $x$ then integrate $\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $u=\log_2 x$ then $du= \dfrac {dx} {x\log_e 2}$.  If $dv=\sqrt{x}\,dx$ then $v = \dfrac 2 3 x^{3/2}$.  So you get
\begin{align}
& \int u\,dv=vu-\int v\, du = \frac 2 3 x^{3/2}\log_2 x - \int\frac 2 3 x^{3/2}\frac{dx}{x\log_e 2} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 2 3 x^{3/2}\log_2 x - \frac{2}{3\log_e 2} \int x^{3/2}\frac {dx} x \\[8pt]
= {} &  \frac 2 3 x^{3/2}\log_2 x - \frac{2}{3\log_e 2} \int x^{1/2}\, dx= \cdots
\end{align}
Here I used the fact that $x^{3/2}\dfrac 1 x= x^{1/2}$.  Strangely, I have found that simple point to be a place where students get stuck after getting everything else right.

Comment: could I also get a hint for the integral of x(ln(x)) ? My idea was to set u as ln(x) and dv as x. Is there a better way?

Comment: $dv$ would be $x\,dx$, not just $x$.  Other than that, that's the way to do it.